# ¿Por qué no me muestra los datos en la pagina 2 usando pagination en Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Bueno días, estoy haciendo un proyecto en Laravel 5.1 y quiero mostrar los datos usando la paginación pero solo me los muestra los en la primera pagina

Código del Controlador

```
public function verUsDepar(Request $request){
        $id_dep=$request->get('id_dep');

        $usuarios=\DB::table('usuario')
                    ->where('id_departamento','=',$id_dep)
                    ->Paginate(10);

        $datos= [
            'usuarios' => $usuarios
        ];

        return view('verUsuarios', $datos);
    }
```

Código de la vista

```
<div class="container offset-sm-2" >
        <div class="row">
        @foreach($usuarios as $us)
        <div class="card col-sm-4 " style='margin: 30px; background-color: lightblue'>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class='card-title'>{!! $us->email !!}</h4>
                <h5 class="card-title">{!! $us->nombre !!}<?php echo " ";?>{!! $us->apellido !!}</h5>

                <div class="btn-group">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Opciones</button>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" style='background-color: #007BFF;'>
                                @if(\Session::get('rol')=='0')
                                    @if($us->validado==0)
                                    <form name="validar" action="validar" method="POST">
                                        {!! csrf_field() !!}
                                        <input type="hidden" name="mail" value="{!! $us->email !!}">
                                        <input type="submit" name="validar" value="Activar" class="btn btn-warning" id="boton">
                                    </form>
                                    @elseif($us->validado!=0)
                                    <form name="desvalidar" action="desvalidar" method="POST">
                                        {!! csrf_field() !!}
                                        <input type="hidden" name="mail" value="{!! $us->email !!}">
                                        <input type="submit" name="desvalidar" value="Desactivar" class="btn btn-primary" id="boton">
                                    </form>
                                    @endif
                                @endif
                                <form name="modificarUs" action="modificarUs" method="POST">
                                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                                    <input type="hidden" name="nombre" value="{!! $us->nombre !!}">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="apellido" value="{!! $us->apellido !!}">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="mail" value="{!! $us->email !!}">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="contra" value="{!! $us->contra !!}">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id_dep" value="{!! $us->id_departamento !!}">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="validado" value="{!! $us->validado !!}">
                                    <input type="submit" name="modificarUs" value="Modificar Usuario" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%;">
                                </form>
                                <form name="borrarUs" action="borrarUS" method="POST">
                                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                                    <input type="hidden" name="mail" value="{!! $us->email !!}">
                                    <input type="submit" name="borrarUs" value="Borrar Usuario" class="btn btn-primary">
                                </form>

                                <form name="verMacs" action="verMacUs" method="POST">
                                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                                    <input type="hidden" name="mail" value="{!! $us->email !!}">
                                    <input type="submit" name="verMac" value="Ver MAC" class="btn btn-primary">
                                </form>
                            @if(\Session::get('rol')=='0')
                                <form name="cambiarROl" action="cambiarRol" method="POST">
                                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                                    <input type="hidden" name="mail" value="{!! $us->email !!}">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id_dep" value="{!! $us->id_departamento !!}">
                                    <input type="submit" name="cambiarRol" value="Hacer Jefe Departamento" class="btn btn-primary">
                                </form>
                            @endif
                                <form name="agregarMAC" action="agregMAC" method="POST">
                                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                                    <input type="hidden" name="mail" value="{!! $us->email !!}">
                                    <input type="submit" name="agregarMAC" value="Agregar MAC" class="btn btn-primary">
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
</div>
</div>
{!! $usuarios->render() !!}

En la ruta

Route::any('verUsDepar', ['uses' => 'controladorAdmin@verUsDepar', 'as' => 'verUsDepar']);
```

Comment: Revisando el código lo único que se me ocurre es: ¿Hay más de 10 resultados? Y perdona la pregunta.

Comment: Si, si que hay mas de 10 resultados

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el html resultante? La parte de los enlaces de la paginación.

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de echarle un ojo a la consulta,               
<ul class="pagination">
        <li class="disabled">
            <span>&laquo;</span>
        </li> 
        <li class="active">
            <span>1</span>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/administracionMACs/public/verUsDepar?page=2">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/administracionMACs/public/verUsDepar?page=3">3</a></li> 
        <li><a href="http://localhost/administracionMACs/public/verUsDepar?page=2" rel="next">&raquo;</a></li>
    </ul>

Comment: Por lo que veo, a riesgo de equivocarme, es que tu ruta en los enlaces es: localhost/administracionMACs/public/verUsDepar. Y la del archivo rutas es: localhost/administracionMACs/verUsDepar, lo que me parece raro es que no te de un error 404.

Comment: Yo al crear el proyecto en netbeans en la ruta desde la cual se ejecuta el proyecto (project URL) le pongo public, por eso al indicar la ruta en el archivo routes.php no le pongo public ni nada asi

Comment: Y en la barra del navegador, la de la url, ¿qué pone?

Comment: http://localhost/administracionMACs/public/verUsDepar

Comment: Por lo que veo del código... html, bien; php, bien; rutas, ¿?... creo que el problema está en la ruta. No veo que pueda ser otra cosa.

Comment: Yo creo que también puede estar en la ruta, pero no se donde porque todo lo demás sale bien, ademas la paginación la uso en otras partes de la aplicación y me va bien, es solo en este punto donde va mal

Comment: De dónde obtenés el valor de `id_dep` al cargar la página 1? Es muy probable que al clickear el link para ir a la página 2, como `id_dep` no está ingresado como parámetro en dicha URL, `id_dep` no existe y por eso la query no trae resultados. Pero no entiendo porque funcionaría la primera vez. Cuál es la URL completa para acceder a la página 1?

Comment: el id_dep lo cojo de un type hidden que tengo en la pagina desde la que accedo para ver los usuarios de ese departamento, la url de la pagina 1 es: http://localhost/administracionMACs/public/verUsDepar

Comment: Haz un dd de $request y pon el resultado

Comment: este es el resultado del dd del request "1", y si hago un dd del resultado a la consulta de la base de datos para la paginacion: LengthAwarePaginator {#265 ▼
  #total: 26
  #lastPage: 3
  #items: Collection {#263 ▼
    #items: array:10 [▼  datos...  ]
  }
  #perPage: 10
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "http://localhost/administracionMACs/public/verUsDepar"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
}

Comment: @Cristina podrías hacer un `dd($id_dep)` al cargar la página 2?

Answer (score -1):

En tu return hazlo asi:

```
    return view('verUsuarios', compact ('usuarios'))
```

La ruta es post

Comment: Revisar [answer].